# Restricción campo de texto PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

como puedo validar en PostgreSQL para que no permita ingresar comillas en un campo de tipo cadena.

Comment: Puedes poner una regular expresion como constraint

Answer (score 3):

Puedes usar un constraint `CHECK` de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE prueba (col1 text);

ALTER TABLE prueba 
ADD CONSTRAINT sin_comillas 
    CHECK (col1 NOT LIKE '%"%');
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]